# Risk Register & Project Summary Risk Report

Tags: project-management-style, risk

What is the link between Risk Register Database & Project Summary Risk Reports and other risk management and project management procedures?

Comment: Hi. Could you possible add a bit more detail to your question? Do you have a particular concern about how these reports are used?

Comment: A note just from my experience: The Risk Register Database is the place I've kept the living activities of Risk Management (the risk, description, impact, mitigation  steps, probabilities, etc.), and the Project Summary Risk Report (called many other things by many other people) is the discussion of a snapshot of the risk in the database. Usually this is used for reporting to upper management to communicate what is the current state of risk to a project and what is the highest risk. All the other procedures either create or reduce risk, which is expressed in the database. Just my history.

Answer (score 1):

[Risk Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_register) Database - just a list of risks with all it's attributes. Typically excel or SQL table, that is constantly reviewed.

Project Summary Risk Reports - it's a report made of this [Risk Register](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_register) Database. Typically risk matrix, and number of pivot tables/nice looking charts, giving you high-level overview of risk impacts in total, by date, by category, by strategy, by owner and ROI of mitigation/contingency .

Answer (score 0):

It seems (based on some Google searches) that the *Risk Register Database* is used to track the progress and status of the risks identified. This is updated very frequently, to ensure the project remains on track, by removing/mitigating the risks identified.

The *Project Summary Risk Report* would be the master list of issues that were identified - the result of a risk analysis process. This list fed the Risk Register Database, but it remains static (unless new risks are identified), to provide a baseline.

There may be other names for these documents.

The only other Risk Document I can think of is the result of a post-mortem, where the Project Summary Risk Report is compared to the Risk Register Database and lessons learned are added to the list of things to consider in future project planning.

Answer (score 0):

The Risk Register Database tracks all risks (risks, issues and opportunities) for the project. The database benefits the project manager and the project team.

The Project Summary Risk Reports are influenced my the end users, stakeholders, project champion and the Project Management Office (PMO). All of these groups will want certain information in the reports. The PMO may set a minimum of what is included. The other three may want to know about risks that only effect the project by certain schedule shifts, cost changes or performance requirements that do not meet expectations. The threshold for what goes into the Risk Reports is set-up in project planning, and it may even go back as far as declaring project management standards from the PMO in the project charter.